# Rest api for Salesforce Markting Cloud (ExactTarget) returns Categories from Parent Business Unit

Tags: exacttarget, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I have two business units in my `salesforce` marketing cloud account with different folders structures. For example Parent Business Unit (PBU) has 3 folders by name `ABC, PQR, and XYZ` and Child Business Unit(CBU) has 2 folders by name `AA,BB`.

When I run the OAuth2.0 end point get the token using client id and secret of CBU and pass the token to get categories endpoint, the response gives me categories of the PBU i.e. `ABC,PQR,XYZ`.

Is there any setting in salesforce which I need to do which will return assets of specific BUs using rest endpoints?

Thanks,
Swapnil

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add the clientID within your API code to get the data from the specific Business Unit. This document will be helpful - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/using_clientid_in_your_soap_api_code.htm